# SWT List drag and drop: Get element at drop location

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, swt

Hi I have a SWT list and I want to be able to change the order of the items in the list by Drag and Drop.
I have a partly implemented code. I am not sure how do I get the element where the drop occurs,  i.e get the item where the draged item is released (so that I can swap it with the draged item).
Here is the code I have so far:

```
    listComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    documentList = new List(listComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    Transfer[] types = new Transfer[] { TextTransfer.getInstance() };
    DragSource source = new DragSource(documentList, DND.DROP_MOVE | DND.DROP_COPY);
    source.setTransfer(types);

    source.addDragListener(new DragSourceAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void dragSetData(DragSourceEvent event)
        {
            // Get the selected items in the drag source
            DragSource ds = (DragSource) event.widget;
            List list = (List) ds.getControl();
            String[] selection = list.getSelection();
            event.data = selection[0];
        }
    });
    DropTarget target = new DropTarget(documentList, DND.DROP_MOVE | DND.DROP_COPY
            | DND.DROP_DEFAULT);
    target.setTransfer(types);
    target.addDropListener(new DropTargetAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void dragEnter(DropTargetEvent event)
        {
            if (event.detail == DND.DROP_DEFAULT)
            {
                event.detail = (event.operations & DND.DROP_COPY) != 0 ? DND.DROP_COPY
                        : DND.DROP_NONE;
            }

            // Allow dropping text only
            for (int i = 0, n = event.dataTypes.length; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (TextTransfer.getInstance().isSupportedType(event.dataTypes[i]))
                {
                    event.currentDataType = event.dataTypes[i];
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void dragOver(DropTargetEvent event)
        {
            event.feedback = DND.FEEDBACK_SELECT | DND.FEEDBACK_SCROLL;
        }

        @Override
        public void drop(DropTargetEvent event)
        {
            if (TextTransfer.getInstance().isSupportedType(event.currentDataType))
            {
                  //HELP: How to get the element were the drop occurs and swap it with the draged element.
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Got this thing to work. Might not be the best solution but this is what I came up with.

```
@Override
        public void drop(DropTargetEvent event)
        {
            String sourceItemIndex = (String) event.data;
            String targetItemIndex = null;
            if (TextTransfer.getInstance().isSupportedType(event.currentDataType))
            {
                int dropYCordinate = event.y
                        - documentList.toDisplay(documentList.getLocation()).y;
                int itemTop = 0;
                // Search for the item index where the drop took place
                for (int i = 0; i < documentList.getItemCount(); i++)
                {

                    if (dropYCordinate >= itemTop
                            && dropYCordinate <= itemTop + documentList.getItemHeight())
                    {
                        targetItemIndex = documentList.getTopIndex() + i + "";
                    }
                    itemTop += documentList.getItemHeight();
                }
            }
            swapListItems(Integer.parseInt(sourceItemIndex), Integer.parseInt(targetItemIndex));
        }
    });
```

Basically I get the Y coodrdinate of the point where the item was dropped and check for the item which overlaps that Y coordinate. Once I get the target, all I need to do is switch the source and the target item. Hope this helps someone trying to do something similair.

Answer (score 1):

## For a table or a tree

Just in addition if someone has the same problem but uses a table or a tree: there is an `item` attribute in the `DropTargetEvent`.

> **event.item** (`Widget`)
>   If the associated control is a table or tree, this field contains the item located at the cursor coordinates.

(Source: [Eclipse Help - DropTargetEvent](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fdnd%2FDropTargetEvent.html))